# Getting JPEG with android

Tags: android, image, url, jpeg

What is the laziest method to get JPEG from url and get it to use in my app?
I would like to achieve it without any new libraries to my project.

Sincerely,
Peter.

Comment: What does "laziest" mean in this context?

Comment: I want that method be quick and easy.

Comment: Easy, well-implemented, and avoid libraries: pick any two.

Answer (score 1):

```
URL webUrl = new URL("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/cool.png");
URLConnection connection = webUrl.openConnection();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

but beware you can't run this code on `UI Thread`, it should be done on `Thread` or `AsyncTask`

Comment: This will not handle HTTP errors well. It does not handle downsampling at all (to minimize the memory footprint of the image). It does not handle caching at all. It does not handle `Bitmap` reuse (e.g., `inBitmap` on `BitmapFactory.Options`).

Answer (score 0):

*You can also use **ImageLoader***

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

//your image url
String url = "http://javatechig.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/UniversalImageLoader-620x405.jpg";

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(fallback)
                .showImageOnFail(fallback)
                .showImageOnLoading(fallback).build();

//initialize image view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)     

//download and display image from url
imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);
```

*For more details , you can visit this post* [ImageLoader](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android)